# more then one expression in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, strip

i want to use a list comprehension to split elements of a list.

`line = [x.split(", ") for x in lineList]`

At same time I'd like to remove tailing and leading characters of the elements `(.rstrip('"')/.lstrip('"')`.

But a 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'. Is there a way to achieve this within a comprehension or do i have to go for a for-loop?

Thanks in advance for any advice,
Lars

Comment: if you are trying to parse a json list then use `json.loads()` instead or if it is string list's `repr()` then use `ast.literal_eval()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove both leading and trailing quotes, why not using `strip()` directly? Also, if you want to flatten the list of lists:

```
line = sum([[y.strip('"') for y in x.split(", ")] for x in lineList], [])
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your answers. Exactly what i was looking for but couldn't come up with. Cheers!

Comment: @LarsVegas: [`sum(nested_list, [])` is an inefficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python#comment13288147_952946) and it is not the most readable way to [flatten a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/4279)

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this :

```
line = [[y.rstrip('"') for y in x.split(", ")] for x in lineList]
```

with two list comprehensions inside.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find the nested list comprehension harder to read.  Why not give this work to another function?  Perhaps this deserves a better name, but:

```
def groom_line(l):
    return [elem.strip('"') for elem in l.split(",")]
```

and in your application,

```
return [groom_line(l) for l in linelist]
```